# Can't add href and class to list item through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<li id="video_button"><a href="#"></a></li>
```

JS:

```
if(ajax_status.responseText == "ready") {
  document.getElementById("video_button").innerHTML = "START";
  document.getElementById("video_button").onclick = function() {send_cmd("ca 1");};
  halted = 0;
}
else if(ajax_status.responseText == "video") {
  document.getElementById("video_button").innerHTML = "STOP";
  document.getElementById("video_button").onclick = function() {send_cmd("ca 0");};
}
```

As I tag the list item through javascript, it won't recognize `<a href="#"> </a>` on the HTML code. This way, it's receiving class from something else in my CSS code.

How do I add href and class to it through JS?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to edit `href` on that `a` tag inside `li`?

Comment: I'd like to add the entire ```a``` tag with ```href``` in it. This, way it'd (hopefully) grab the correct class from CSS (```#nav > ul > li > a {```). I'd probably need to add the class from javascript too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that it? Just adding `a` tag with given `href`?

```
if(ajax_status.responseText == "ready") {
  document.getElementById("video_button").innerHTML = "<a href='start'>Start</a>";
  document.getElementById("video_button").onclick = function() {send_cmd("ca 1");};
  document.getElementById("video_button").classList.add("myClass"); // Add Class
  halted = 0;
}
else if(ajax_status.responseText == "video") {
  document.getElementById("video_button").innerHTML = "<a href='stop'>Stop</a>";
  document.getElementById("video_button").onclick = function() {send_cmd("ca 0");};
  document.getElementById("video_button").classList.remove("myClass"); // Remove Class
}
```

Comment: Is there also a way to add class to the ```li```tag? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading about [Element.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).